# Discordjs 14.7.1 Skips First Reaction

Tags: discord, discord.js

Problem is the Discord bot is skipping the first reaction emoji.
If I un-react and re-react with the same emoji, then the bot registers it.

I've been trying to figure this out for a while, and am stumped as to what I am missing in my logic or if I need to find another solution.

Intention:

- Discord bot gathers and prints out all reactions to a message by a user

Relevant Information:

Discordjs 14.7.1

Discord Developer Website:

- Presence Intent: Enabled
- Server Members Intent: Enabled
- Message Content Intent: Enabled

Code:

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./includes/config.json');

// create a new discord client
const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageTyping,
    GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.Reaction,
    Partials.User,
  ]
});

// ready
client.once(Events.ClientReady, () => {
  console.log('Ready!');
});

// if partial, fetch full
client.on(Events.MessageReactionAdd, async (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.partial) {
    try {
      await reaction.fetch();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      return;
    }
  }

// define the message component
const message = reaction.message;

// all userReactions by user.id
const userReactions = await message.reactions.cache.filter(reaction => reaction.users.cache.has(user.id));

// print emojis
try {
  for (const reaction of userReactions.values()) {
    console.log(`Emoji: ${reaction.emoji}`);
  }
} catch(error) {
  console.error(error);
}
})

// login
client.login(token);
```

Problem:

- The bot is not registering the first reaction placed

```
Example:
- I react to a message in this order: ❤️
- the logfile shows:
Emoji: ❤️
Emoji: ❤️
Emoji: 

Expected result:
Emoji: 
Emoji: 
Emoji: ❤️
Emoji: 
Emoji: ❤️
Emoji:
```

Observations:

- I noticed that the bot works fine for all messages sent after it is running
- The problematic behaviour is experienced only for messages sent before the bot was running

Conclusion:

- MessageReactionAdd() does get called, as tested by placing 'console.log(`test output`); statements. I learned that it works on cached messages only, which I thought was mitigated by fetching the full reaction. Such was not the case. I tried testing by forcing a message fetch manually by channel.id and message.id, it still did not work.

My Solution:

- Used an sqlite database to keep track of reactions.
- From within MessageReactionAdd() I was able to check for the reactions I was interested in logging, and added them to an sqlite database.
- Within an equivalent MessageReactionRemove() section, I was able to check for removal of the reactions and delete the pertinent row from the database.

Thank you for reading and assisting. :)

Comment: Have you tried [using collectors](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#reaction-collectors) instead, as suggested on the official Discord.js guide?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Collectors, but will be learning that when I can.

Comment: @VishnuBhagyanath, thank you for your assistance. I will definitely give Collectors a look and see if I can learn to apply them to another variation of this project.